# Loop within loop used on multi-dimensional array to group data possible?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to output grouped data from a multidimensional array. Consider the highest level array key the 'group', then within the groups are the individual search lines.

e.g. `$group[ 0 ][ 1 ]` would be 'group 1, line 1'.

I want to display all the lines from each group, then signify that the group has changed by inserting an '`<hr />`' tag. At the moment the first group displays properly, then the hr tag is shown but then none of the second group results display. Is my method of loop within loop wrong? Is it possible to use multi dimensional array like this?
Thanks!!

My array looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => testing
                [searchID] => 131
                [lineID] => 190
                [searchString] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => testing
                [searchID] => 131
                [lineID] => 191
                [searchString] => 2
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => testing
                [searchID] => 131
                [lineID] => 192
                [searchString] => 3
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => testing
                [searchID] => 131
                [lineID] => 193
                [searchString] => 4
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => test2
                [searchID] => 132
                [lineID] => 199
                [searchString] => 1
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => test2
                [searchID] => 132
                [lineID] => 200
                [searchString] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

My code looks like this:

```
 $x = 0;
 $y = 0;
 while( $x < count( $groups ) )
 {
 while( $y < count( $groups[ $x ] ) )
 {
     //display each single search string
    echo $groups[ $x ][ $y ]->searchString.'<br>';
    $y++; 
 }
 echo '<hr>';
 $x++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your example array, the y value of your second group should start on 4 and loop until it reaches 6.

I would recommend you using foreach loops. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Your code would look as follows:

```
foreach ( $groups as $gKey => $gValue )
{
    foreach ( $gValue as $key => $value )
    {
        echo $groups[$gKey][$key]->searchString . "<br />";
        // or $value->searchString . "<br />";
    }
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

Comment: This works and is so much more simple and elegant than my way. I'm definitely going to do it like this in the future, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
foreach ( $groups as $group ) {
    foreach ( $group as $var ) {
        echo $var->searchString, "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt the second loop be on group? Not groups

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset `y` inside the first loop.

```
$x = 0;
while( $x < count( $groups ) )
{
    $y = 0;
    while( $y < count( $groups[ $x ] ) )
    {
        //display each single search string
        echo $groups[ $x ][ $y ]->searchString.'<br>';
        $y++; 
    }
     echo '<hr>';
     $x++;
}
```

Comment: I dont think so, because the second key ( [x]  >> [y] << ) does not start from 0 for every new group, please check the array i provided. I tried resetting y and get this notice

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ... on line 423

Comment: @KelseyThorpe Then using a while is not going to work because `count($groups[$x]$y])` on the second loop will be 2 but `y` will equal 4

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach:

```
foreach ($groups as $x => $group )
{
    foreach ($group as $y => $subGroup )
    {
        echo $subGroup->searchString . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```